# @JsonView annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, kotlin, jackson

I am trying to deserialize several fields from my object in Spring using the `@JsonView` annotation. However, I add the annotation to my method, instead of deserializing the specified field, it returns an empty object.

Here is my POJO:

```
@Entity
data class Album(
        @JsonView(View.AlbumSummary::class)
        val title: String,

        @JsonView(View.AlbumSummary::class)
        @ManyToMany
        val artists: List<Account>,

        val dateReleased: LocalDate,

        val genre: String = GENRE_NA,

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "album")
        val songs: List<Song> = ArrayList(),

        val description: String = ""
)
```

And also, the method that implements the `@JsonView` annotation:

```
@JsonView(View.AlbumSummary::class)
@RequestMapping("/home-recommendations/{userId}")
fun getHomeRecommendations(@PathVariable userId: String): List<Recommendation> {

    val recommendations = ArrayList<Recommendation>()

    val user = accountRepository.findById(userId).get()
    val followingArtists = user.following.filter {
        it.following.isArtist
    }
    val suggestedArtists = followingArtists.shuffled().take(Random().nextInt(11) + 10)

    for (i in 0 until suggestedArtists.size) {

        val suggestedArtist = suggestedArtists[i].following

        val recommendedAlbums = suggestedArtist.albums.shuffled().take(Random().nextInt(6) + 10)

        recommendations.add(Recommendation("Because you listened to ${suggestedArtist.fullName}", Recommendation.TYPE_ALBUM, albums = recommendedAlbums))

    }

    return recommendations

}
```

Edit: My gradle configuration:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.50'
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-jpa'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.aceinteract'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
}
```

I can provide more code if needed. Thanks in advance.

P.S. The same code works perfectly when the `@JsonView` annotation is removed from the method

Also, I'm using IntelliJ Idea

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi No, I don't use proguard

Comment: Can you add your gradle file here.

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi it has been added

Comment: Yes let me check it

Comment: Are you getting error at runtime?

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi No, I am not getting any error at runtime.

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi No, I am not getting any error at runtime.

Comment: Than? at compile?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174339/discussion-between-ace-falobi-and-brijesh-joshi).

Answer (score 1):

1. As said in documentation of [FasterXML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin). If using **proguard**, kotlin.Metadata annotations may be stripped, preventing deserialization. Add a proguard rule to keep the kotlin.Metadata class: `-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }`
2. Try using `@field:JsonView(View.AlbumSummary::class)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea how to add proguard to my project?

Comment: There will be a file name `proguard-rules.pro` in your app module already. That is your proguard file

Comment: I can't find any proguard-rules file in my app or project module

Comment: Create a file `proguard-rules.pro` in your app module. And than from the **app settings->Flavours->Proguard File** select your  created file there it will be than added to your project

Comment: WOW `@field:JsonView` works for me. Thank you!
Why this information is not highly documented?..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [Jackson Module for Kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) on your classpath and registered on an instance of ObjectMapper.

Comment: Yes, I have the Jackson Module for Kotlin. It's also worth noting that I have used other Jackson annotations in this same project like `@JsonIgnoreProperties` and `@JsonIgnore`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and the JsonView only worked after I moved the fields out of the constructor and into the class body. You wouldn't use a data class in this case, but you can still delegate equals hashcode toString to a private inner data class.